# Is Selemium IDE deprecated?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

From the windows command prompt I run

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.50.0.jar -htmlsuite "*firefox"
>   "http://localhost" "c:\my-test-suite.html"
>   "c:\my-test-suite-results.html"

The results file shows this message

"info: Selenium 1.0 (Core, RC, etc) is no longer under active development. Please update to WebDriver ASAP"

I am using Selenium IDE to generate the test suite html file.

Can I safely ignore this error message or should I give up on Selenium IDE?

Answer (score 2):

Selenium IDE is not deprecated and you may use it to record\replay scripts.
Actually you may export tests from the Selenium IDE to run with WebDriver (for C#, Java or Ruby).

[Selenium WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) is enchanced version (I'd say next generation) of the Selenium RC so it's more powerfull and flexible, and it's under active development to support actual browser versions.
Selenium RC is still maintained but **not developed** so in fact you may safely continue with it as long as it satisfies your needs.